# Swagger with embedded Jetty

Tags: java, swagger, embedded-jetty

Can someone please let me know if this is the right way to configure Swagger with embedded jetty.

```
public class TestMain {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Server gs = new Server();
    ServletContextHandler sch = gs.getServletContextHandler();

    sch.addFilter(new FilterHolder(new RequestTrackerFilter()), "/*",     EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST));
    sch.addFilter(new FilterHolder(new ActionIdFilter()), "/*", EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST));

    ResourceHandler resource_handler = new ResourceHandler();
    resource_handler.setDirectoriesListed(false);

    resource_handler.setResourceBase("public/2.0");

    ContextHandler context = new ContextHandler("/apitest");

    context.setHandler(resource_handler);

    ContextHandlerCollection contexts = new ContextHandlerCollection();


   setupSwaggerContextHandler();

  //     context.getServletContext().addListener(new SwaggerInitializer());

    contexts.setHandlers(new Handler[]{sch, context});

    gs.getServer().setHandler(contexts);

    gs.start();
}

private static ServletContextHandler setupSwaggerContextHandler() {
    // Configure Swagger-core
    final ServletHolder swaggerServletHolder = new ServletHolder(new JerseyJaxrsConfig());
    swaggerServletHolder.setName("JerseyJaxrsConfig");
    swaggerServletHolder.setInitParameter("api.version", "1.0.0");
    swaggerServletHolder.setInitParameter("swagger.api.basepath", "http://localhost:9000/apitest");
    swaggerServletHolder.setInitOrder(2);

    final ServletContextHandler swaggerContextHandler = new ServletContextHandler();
    swaggerContextHandler.setSessionHandler(new SessionHandler());
    // Bind Swagger-core to the url HOST/api-docs
    swaggerContextHandler.setContextPath("/api-docs");
    swaggerContextHandler.addServlet(swaggerServletHolder, "/*");

    return swaggerContextHandler;
  }
}
```

I am not able to see any output using

```
  http://localhost:9000/apitest/api-docs
```

Am following the discussion at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/swagger-swaggersocket/KHYESESD6c4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using swagger-core 1.5.x, you need to be looking under the context path for `/swagger.json`.  Thus for your setup:

`http://localhost:9000/apitest/api-docs/swagger.json`

Comment: I am able to get it working, but please let me know how to generate single swagger.json manually. I am getting multiple json file for multiple apis. Is it normal ?

Comment: Hi, happy to help if you can please share more information.  It might be best discussed in the Google Group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/swagger-swaggersocket

Comment: I found out that there is one top level json which has entries for the apis. i.e., swagger.json file. I am using Swagger Plugin in my pom.xml to generate the json

Answer (score 6):

I played around a lot to get Swagger to work with embedded Jetty with no `web.xml` or Spring, and finally ended up with this solution:
https://github.com/SriramKeerthi/swagger-jersey2-jetty

I would have added it as a comment if I had enough reputation. But that is the simplest version of the code I could come up with. You need two parts:

1. Swagger Bean Config:

   ```
   BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
   beanConfig.setVersion("1.0.0");
   beanConfig.setResourcePackage(YourJerseyResourceClass.class.getPackage().getName());
   beanConfig.setScan(true);
   beanConfig.setBasePath("/");
   beanConfig.setDescription("Sample API to demonstrate Swagger with Jersey2" +
           " in an embedded Jetty instance, with no web.xml or Spring MVC.");
   beanConfig.setTitle("Sample API");
   ```
2. Add:

   ```
   ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig();
   // Add your resources and Swagger resources (ApiListingResource package)
   resourceConfig.packages(YourJerseyResourceClass.class.getPackage().getName(), ApiListingResource.class.getPackage().getName());
   ServletContainer servletContainer = new ServletContainer(resourceConfig);
   ServletHolder servletHolder = new ServletHolder(servletContainer);
   ServletContextHandler servletContextHandler = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
   servletContextHandler.setContextPath("/");
   servletContextHandler.addServlet(servletHolder, "/*");
   ```

You should now be able to see the Swagger [`spec`](http://swagger.io/specification/) at the `/swagger.json` endpoint.

P.S. The team at #swagger on irc.freenode.net is brilliant, you should visit them if nothing gets fixed.

Comment: Wonderful link : https://github.com/SriramKeerthi/swagger-jersey2-jetty 
It works :)

Comment: This is one of the best examples I have come across. Kudos to you. I do have a question on this though. The **swaggerui** folder under Resources, how did you come by this? Was this something created by you or was this some default swagger UI folder you came across?

Comment: @siddhusingh but the github uses jaxrs. If I am using jetty 11 which is part of Jakarta EE 9 big bang, I think all namespaces of jaxrs.* will be useless. Do you know if we can use Sriram's link for jetty 11?

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck in for hours before I found a solution. Adding it here although my config was slightly different from OP. For my case I needed only a couple of lines of configuration to be plugged into my embedded Jetty and RestService

```
// Jetty configuration

// ContextHandlerCollection contexts

ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
context.setContextPath("/api");
context.addFilter(GzipFilter.class, "/*", EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class));

ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig(ImmutableSet.<Class<?>>builder()
                                                                .add(MyRestService.class)
                                                                .build());
// BELOW LINE WAS THE ONLY THING IN JETTY THAT WAS NEEDED               
resourceConfig.packages( ApiListingResource.class.getPackage().getName() );

context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer(resourceConfig)), "/*");
contexts.addHandler(context);
```

And on the rest service I had to add:

```
@Api(value = "MyRestService")
public class MyRestService
{
    @ApiOperation(notes = "Get object api", value = "Get objects")
    public Response getObjects() {....}

}
```

**EDIT**
If you wish to configure the swagger attributes like basepath, you can configure using `BeanConfig` which is self contained:

```
BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
        beanConfig.setVersion( "1.0.0" );
        beanConfig.setResourcePackage( SalusRestService.class.getPackage().getName() );
        beanConfig.setScan( true );
        beanConfig.setBasePath( "/api/v1" );
        beanConfig.setDescription( "Entity Browser API to demonstrate Swagger with Jersey2 in an " + "embedded Jetty instance, with no web.xml or Spring MVC." );
        beanConfig.setTitle( "Entity Browser" );
```